# Expectation and waiting time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning

> There are three jobs that need to be processed, with the processing
>   time of job $i$ being exponential with rate $\mu_i$. There are two
>   processors available, so processing on two of the jobs can immediately
>   start, with processing on the final job to start when one of the
>   initial ones is finished.
>
> $(a)$ Let $T_i$ denote the time at which the processing of job $i$ is
>   completed. If the objective is to minimize $\mathbb E[T_1 + T_2 + T_3]$ , which
>   jobs should be initially processed if $\mu_1 < \mu_2 < \mu_3$?

Intuitively believe that the right would be to start by processes that require more average processing time $2,3$

But I can not understand mathematically where it comes from. Suppose that I don't know that $u_1<u_2<u_3$
$$\mathbb E[T_1+T_2+T_3]=\mathbb E[T_1]+\mathbb E[T_2]+\mathbb E[T_3]=\frac{1}{\mu_1}+\frac{1}{\mu_2}+\frac{1}{\mu_3}$$
I do not really see the difference in the end processing time, starting with any of the processes

Comment: If $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are the actual amounts of clock time that the three jobs took (from start to end), can you express $T$, the time when all three jobs are finished as functions of $X_1, X_2, X_3$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Looking back, it seems that there is little point being the sum of the times, since two processes are done simultaneously

Comment: So, **what are you asking for?**

Comment: @DilipSarwate I want so solve the item $a)$, I was just thinking about the general case.

Comment: The quantity $E[T_1 + T_2 + T_3]$ corresponds to nothing of interest. Sure this is what the text is asking?

Comment: @Did good point, I would assume that we're instead looking to minimize $\mathbb E[\max_i T_i]$.

Comment: @Math1000 This would be my conjecture as well, but only the OP (who was on the site since my previous comment) can tell.

Comment: @Did I transcribed exactly as it is in the book, the Ross's book exercises are more difficult to understand than done.

Comment: Which book and which problem, exactly?

Comment: @Math1000 Here is the book [Ross](http://bayanbox.ir/view/7776870545953264619/introduction-to-probability-model-S.Ross-math-cs.blog.ir.pdf) page number 356, exercise number 16, chapter 5

Comment: Already had the text and found the problem before you posted. A solution manual is available on the internet as well..

Comment: @Math1000 I have the book solution, I'm using that to have solution, since I'm studying alone. But sometimes I can not quite understand the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Chapter 5, Exercise 16 of *Introduction to Probability Models* by Sheldon Ross ($10^{\mathrm{th}}$) edition. I am not sure that the solution given is actually correct:

[image: Solution]

Let $X_n\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\mu_n)$. If we suppose jobs $i$ and $j$ are initially begun, then the expected time until job $k$ starts is
$$\mathbb E[X_i \wedge X_j] = \frac1{\mu_i+\mu_j}. $$
The remaining time, conditioned on $X_i<X_j$, is $X_j \vee X_k+ X_j\wedge X_k$, and as $$X_j+X_k \stackrel d= X_j\vee X_k+X_j\wedge X_k,$$
we have
$$\mathbb E[X_j\vee X_k+X_j\wedge X_k] = \mathbb E[X_j+X_k] = \frac1{\mu_j}+\frac1{\mu_k}. $$
Similarly, the expected remaining time, conditioned on $X_j<X_i$ is $\frac1{\mu_i}+\frac1{\mu_k}$. As $\mathbb P(X_i<X_j)=\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i+\mu_j}$ and $\mathbb P(X_j<X_i)=\frac{\mu_j}{\mu_i+\mu_j}$, the total expected time is
\begin{align}
&\mathbb E[X_i\wedge X_j] + \mathbb E[X_j+X_k]\mathbb P(X_i<X_j) + \mathbb E[X_i+X_k]\mathbb P(X_j<X_i)\\
&= \frac1{\mu_i+\mu_j} + \left(\frac1{\mu_j}+\frac1{\mu_k}\right)\left(\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i+\mu_j}\right) +\left(\frac1{\mu_i}+\frac1{\mu_k}\right)\left(\frac{\mu_j}{\mu_i+\mu_j}\right)\\
&= \frac1{\mu_i+\mu_j} +\frac1{\mu_k}+\frac{\mu_i^2+\mu_j^2}{\mu_i\mu_j(\mu_i+\mu_j)}\\
&= \frac1{\mu_k} + \frac{\mu_i^2 + \mu_i\mu_j + \mu_j^2}{\mu_i\mu_j(\mu_i+\mu_j)}\\
&= \frac1{\mu_k}+ \frac{(\mu_i + \mu_j)^2-\mu_i\mu_j}{\mu_i\mu_j(\mu_i+\mu_j)}\\
&= \frac1{\mu_k}+ \frac{\mu_i+\mu_j}{\mu_i\mu_j} - \frac{\mu_i\mu_j}{\mu_i+\mu_j}\\
&= \frac1{\mu_i}+ \frac1{\mu_j}+\frac1{\mu_k} - \frac{\mu_i\mu_j}{\mu_i+\mu_j}.
\end{align}
If there were only one server, then the expected time would be 
$$\frac1{\mu_1}+\frac1{\mu_2}+\frac1{\mu_3} < \frac1{\mu_i}+\frac1{\mu_j} + \frac1{\mu_i+\mu_j} +\frac1{\mu_k}, $$
and it's clear that removing a server cannot reduce the expected waiting time.

Comment: I'll finish this answer later.

Comment: This is much, much simpler than the original approach I was taking!

Comment: I just realized I made an error in this solution. I'll fix it later.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full solution. I simply try to explain how the order of jobs starting affects the min you are after:

if jobs $1$ and $2$ start first the the probability that job $1$ finishes before job $2$ is $$p_{12}=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{t_2}\mu_1\mu_2e^{-\mu_1t_1-\mu_2t_2}dt_1dt_2=\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_1+\mu_2}$$ therefore job $3$ may start with probability $p_{12}$ after job $1$ finishes and with probability $1-p_{12}$ after job $2$ finishes. Hence in this case $$E(T_1+T_2+T_3)=p_{12}E\Big[\max\{T_3,T_2\}\Big]+(1-p_{12})E\Big[\max\{T_3,T_1\}\Big]$$